# What can a hacker do with a non-root user (Linux)?

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow

Let's say I let my friend "Stuart" have an account on my VPS with very limited privileges because he asked very nicely. Since Stuart isn't so bright, he accidentally posts his password in an IRC chatroom, and now everyone and his/her grandma can ssh into his account. My question is, in the hands of an experienced hacker, what kind of damage can be done to the system?

Could someone just write a simple C program to intentionally manipulate a buffer overflow in `strcpy` and serve up a root shell for full control of the system, or are there built-in protections against that in the OS?

Comment: Depends, what sort of privileges will you be giving Stuart?

Comment: you know ... it's an arms race ...

Comment: He can run a fork bomb by example, or try an exploit from a security website, trying some _shellcodes_.

Comment: Let's say he's got rwx in his home directory and r-x everywhere else, and the process limit is set so he can't fork bomb _that_ easily.

Comment: rwx in his home directory is fine. I wouldn't quite give him r-x everywhere else though. There are some files he should not be able to read, execute, or access. A good example is /etc/shadow, or files that belong to root or other users in the system.

Answer (score 3):

There are any number of attackers an attacker with local privileges could perform including but not limited to:

- Fork Bombs
- Accessing services bound to 127.0.0.1
- Using your server as a proxy for malicious attacks
- Serving malicious files from your server
- Local exploits
- Information Leakage
- Mail relaying
- etc

The attack you describe however is not possible as the file would have to have to be owned by root and have the setuid or setgid bits set.

Comment: So hypothetically, if Stuart could find a program owned by root with a buffer overflow vulnerability, then he could access a root shell right?

Comment: If your system has no other safeguards in place and it is setuid then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Once someone has access to the machine, instead of needing a remote exploit, they only need to escalate privileges to have root access.

Remote exploits require having an external publicly-accessible vulnerable service. There shouldn't be any of those running on a standard VPS, assuming that it's being well maintained.

Once a remote user can authenticate, they can execute any code that's on the machine, or bring in more. If there is a bug in the kernel, or in any program that has setuid to root, they can use that to escalate their privileges to a user who has more power - like root.

So a simple buffer overflow in a custom program written by the attacker isn't your concern - that shouldn't allow them to have any extra power. What you're concerned about is a bug in the system that the attacker now has the access, and so, the ability, to exploit.